# Modification of Atom-Field interaction Hamiltonian in the Knight optics textbook

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, calculus

I am reading Quantum optics textbook of Peter Knight.

From the Eq 4.3

$
\hat{H} = \frac{1}{2m}[\hat{P}+e\hat{A}]^2-e\Phi + V(r)
$

Using

$
\hat{H}' = \hat{R}\hat{H}\hat{R}^{\dagger} + i\hbar\frac{\partial \hat{R} }{\partial t}\hat{R}^{\dagger}
$
where $\hat{R}$ = exp$(-ie\chi(\vec{r},t)/\hbar )$

The Hamiltonian is modified by

$
\hat{H} = \frac{1}{2m}[\hat{P}+e(\hat{A}+\nabla\chi) ]^2-e(\Phi-\frac{\partial \chi}{\partial t}) + V(r).
$

This procedure is a little complicated for me.

I tried the first part of the equation

$
\hat{R}\hat{P}^2\hat{R}^{\dagger} \\
= \hat{R} *-\hbar^2\nabla\cdot\nabla(\hat{R}^{\dagger}) \\ 
= e\nabla\chi\cdot\hat{P}-e^2(\nabla\chi)^2
$

This catches away the $\hat{P}^2$ part that should be survived.

What is my fault??

Answer (score 2):

Chapter 14 of https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/3527602976 explains very well these steps, in my opinion.

Instead of developing the term $[P+eA]^2$ it is perhaps better to observe that
$$R[P+eA]^2R^{\dagger}=R[P+eA][P+eA]R^{\dagger}=R[P+eA]I[P+eA]R^{\dagger}=R[P+eA]RR^{\dagger}[P+eA]R^{\dagger}$$
where we use $RR^{\dagger}=I$, since $R$ is unitary. We conclude that
$$R[P+eA]^2R^{\dagger}=\{R[P+eA]R^{\dagger}\}^2$$ and the result follows more easilly.

Comment: It is very helpful and I can derive the modified form by the following textbook. But I think it is impossible to get modified hamiltonian form from the calculation of hamiltonian $\hat{R}H\hat{R}^\dagger$ only